# Gitlab: piping commands with grep not working?

Tags: bash, grep, gitlab, gitlab-ci

The following command in a job script:

```
STATUS_ID=$(grep -Eo "Status Code [0-9]+: Done" somefile | grep -Eo "[0-9]+")
```

Seems to be causing the following ci lint error:

> script config should be a string or an array of strings

The command works fine on my bash however when trying to `grep` the status code via a file containing the line:

> Status Code 8484: Done

What is causing the error on gitlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colon (`:`) makes the line be interpeted as `yaml` map.

The solution (to escape the special meaning of the colon) is to enclose the entire line in single quotes:

```
'STATUS_ID=$(grep -Eo "Status Code [0-9]+: Done" somefile | grep -Eo "[0-9]+")'
```

Comment: what about using single quotes for the `grep`? `STATUS_ID=$(grep -Eo 'Status Code [0-9]+: Done' somefile | grep -Eo "[0-9]+")`